# Socks 4 Bind Request Explanation

Tags: proxy, socks

i was reading this topic
http://ftp.icm.edu.pl/packages/socks/socks4/SOCKS4.protocol

What I'm trying to do is:
I have a client/server application, I'm trying to use socks 4 BIND request to bind my server to a remote socks server, and make the clients connect to that socks server and the socks server will make them connect to my server (at least that's how I understand socks BIND request)

But I don't fully understand it (my English is kinda bad), what I'm asking is, is it possible to do so when I don't know any of the remote IPs of the clients? Since the server's BIND request package must contain the address of the remote client and I don't really have than since the clients are from unknown users retrieving status info from my server (or can I use 0 for INANY_ADDR) ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you are asking for is not possible with SOCKS, nor is it meant for that purpose.  Read the spec again more carefully.  The BIND command is meant for use with multi-connection protocols (like FTP), where a primary connection is used to communicate between a client and a server, and BIND facilitates situations where the server needs to connect a secondary connection to the client after the client tells the server where to connect. In that situation, the client would issue a BIND command to SOCKS telling it the server's IP/Port so it only accepts that connection, then send the resulting SOCKS listening IP/Port to the server to connect to.

What you are asking for is better served by using a router with Port Forwarding rules defined. Then you can open a listening port on the router that accepts any inbound connection and forwards it to your app's listening IP/Port. Most modern routers support uPNP (Universal Plug-N-Play) so you can configure the forwarding rules programmably instead of requiring admin access to the router's configuration software.

Comment: thanks, i understood it better from ur example, got it now, thanks again. i was just looking for away to protect my server, so it it was attacked, the Socks Server will be and not my Local Server.

Comment: Use a router that has anti-attack logic built in.

Comment: Remy, currently I am struggling with socks' rfc. Could you clarify some BIND aspects?  How many inbound connections from a target host can be done on a BINDed socket? Only one? In my opinion this point is not obvious in rfc.

Comment: @sim Once the new socket is bound, it only accepts one connection. After receiving a BIND request, the server sends a maximum of two replies: one after the socket is bound, and another after the anticipated incoming connection succeeds or fails. There is no third reply - further incoming connections are not included in RFC 1928

Comment: @sim reading the SOCKS 4 and 5 specs, the wording is pretty obvious that only 1 inbound connection is allowed per BIND request.

Answer (score 0):

Remy explained it well.
I'd like to add that, if you want to achieve your goal, you can also implement a SOCKS5 server that breaks the protocol a little bit: listen on a specific port for incoming connection (from clients, in your scenario),  accept any incoming connection no matter what the DST.ADDR and DST.PORT is, then relay it to your server.
Watch out for security risk though!